Double envelope bulbs
I have a lamp with the following reference:
Bulb 1000W/220V E40 HALOGEN Double Envelope
What they means by Double Envelope in the reference?

It means exactly what it sounds like, it's a bulb with two envelopes, basically a bulb within a bulb.
This is done for a number of reasons, for one it protects the inner bulb from contamination as halogen bulbs can fail if you get oils from your fingers on them while handling. It can also be used to filter out UV light or it can just be done to make the bulb appear to be a larger size to match conventional incandescent bulbs. The outer bulb will also be cooler which can make them safer than a plain halogen bulb.

Just what it says. There are two envelopes, the internal quartz capsule containing the filament and halogen that gets very hot and an external one that does not get as hot.
I would guess this is for safety reasons since the internal quartz envelope temperature gets to ~550°/1000°F which is more than sufficient to ignite paper etc. It needs to get that hot for the halogen cycle to work and keep tungsten from depositing on the inside of the quartz. The outer one could possibly be made from lower temperature and cheaper material such as glass. As others have pointed out, it also keeps contaminants, including those from the greasy paws of the installer, off the bulb, which can prevent early failures. And, as the answer to a previous question mentioned, using glass rather than quartz as the outer envelope acts as a filter to block harmful UV. Quartz passes UV quite well, which is why germicidal (UV-C) lamps have to have quartz envelopes.

The inner envelope, made of quartz, needs to run hot for the tungsten-halogen recycling to function. The outer bulb can probably be made of conventional glass since it is cooler.

@KevinWhite Good point, edited in. The single-envelope ones in one particular Amazon ad apparently have a "Quarts" envelope.

Also, contaminants on the inner envelope would create local hot spots, which can cause catastrophic failure--given the extreme temperatures the inner envelope sees, it'd be even worse than when it happens to the outer envelope (which is itself why you have to wear gloves when changing the bulb in your typical projector. I'm sure anyone who's given enough presentations is familiar with what happens when you forget!).

@Hearth I've seen one where it burnt a hole in the glass and the filament uncoiled and was sticking out through the hole about 2 inches. When they say not to handle them with your bare hands they're not kidding.
